# How to send mail confirmation after signup in Cakephp 2

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

hello i want send mail after signup , but 
i have a problem , this is UsersController :

```html
public function add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->User->create();
   if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
$link = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'activate', $this->User->id.'-'.md5($this->request->data['User']['password']));    
App::uses('CakeEmail','Network/Email');
$mail = new CakeEmail();
$mail->from('dafhermcslama@gmail.com')
  ->to($this->request->data['User']['email'])
  ->subject('Test :: Inscription')
  ->emailFormat('html')
  ->template('signup')
  ->viewVars(array('username'=>$this->request->data['User']['username'], 'link'=>$link))
  ->send();


    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
    $this->Auth->login($this->data);
    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index'));
    //$this->redirect('/users/index');
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  }
  $countries = $this->User->Country->find('list');
  $cities = $this->User->City->find('list');
  $permits = $this->User->Permit->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('countries', 'cities', 'permits'));
  $this->set('countries', $this->User->City->Country->find('list'));
 }
```

and this is email.php

```html
class EmailConfig {

 public $default = array(
  'transport' => 'Mail',
  'from' => 'dafhermcslama@gmail.com',
  //'charset' => 'utf-8',
  //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
 );
```

and this is php.ini :

```html
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = dafhermcslama@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
;sendmail_path="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"

;sendmail_path = "\"C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and this is View/Email/html/signup.ctp

```html
<p>
 <strong>Bonjour <?php echo $username; ?></strong>
</p>
<p>
 To Activate your profile clic here : 
</p>
<p>
 <?php echo $this->Html->link('Activate', $this->Html->url($link, true)); ?>
</p>
```

but when i register this is the message error :

```html
mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p1sm178880wib.23 - gsmtp
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

what i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some options missing in your `email.php` configuration file. For gmail it should looks like:

```
public $default = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

OR if you use CakePHP 2.3.x+:

```
public $default = array(
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'tls' => true
}
```

More details you can find in [CakeEmail documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html?highlight=cakeemail#configuration).

Comment: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. uc18sm293265wib.0 - gsmtp

Comment: thnx for your update, i dont understand why is also the same error, :/

Comment: SMTP timeout.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred